# Typescript declaration files contain class definitions with no member implementations

Tags: typescript

When I look at the Backbone declaration file I see this:

```
export class Router extends Events {
    ...
    constructor (options?: RouterOptions);
    initialize (options?: RouterOptions);
    ...
}
```

and other places where a class has method definitions with no implementations. I thought this syntax was reserved for interfaces. The compiler lets this pass in the declaration file but not in my own ts files.

Is there a difference between the compilation rules for *.d.ts* vs *.ts* extensions? If so, how should these types of classes be used differently from interfaces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.d.ts` files are for describing an *existing* JavaScript or TypeScript implementation of some class.

A class in a `.d.ts` (I'll just call this a "`declare class`" since they are equivalent) is completely different from a virtual class or an interface. When you declare a `declare class`, you're saying "There is some other class that will be present that has this shape". When you `extend` that class, the compiler is going to emit code on the assumption that there really will be a class (or sufficiently classlike thing) with that name present at runtime to use as the the next pointer in the prototype chain.

Just as an example, this code (by itself) **does not work** - you will get a runtime error because `Foo` isn't defined anywhere:

```
declare class Foo {  public bar(): void; }
class FooDerived extends Foo { }
```

This code, on the other hand, is fine:

```
interface Foo { bar(): void; }
class FooImpl implements Foo { public bar() {} }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. To see for myself, I extended a "declare class" and it is exactly like extending an empty class "class SomeClass { }". I'll look into this "prototype chain" code emitted by the compiler to simulate inheritance, it's a bit confusing. Good answer, thanks.

Comment: But wait, this seems like a problem. The intellisense is nice but what will happen when I call intialize() from an instance of a class that inherits this declare class? The compiler lets it pass, but there is no implementation of this method, not even in the generated javascript. Thus won't it crash at runtime?

Comment: Writing `declare class` means "Compiler, I am *telling you* about a class that *already exists*; please don't generate code here, but do act as if that class will be present at runtime". If you write `declare class` and there isn't actually a class to inherit from, that's going to be a runtime error.

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't make sense to me from a practical perspective. I'm not writing any declare classes and I understand the .d.ts file does not actually generate any code. The last line of your comment suggests I should write an implementation for every declared class in the entire declaration file. Why would I want to inherit from a "declare class" instead of an interface or regular class, which will actually prevent run-time errors?

Comment: I can compare it to "declare var $  : JQueryStatic". There I'm declaring $ of type JQueryStatic FOR THE SAKE OF INTELLISENSE, and if I do not provide an implementation (loading the jQuery library) is will crash at runtime. The same when, INHERITING from a "declare class". I am "promising" to provide implementations for the members before trying to use them, however if I don't, it will crash at run-time. Ultimately I don't see how this construct is beneficial. "declare var $ : JQueryStatic" only exists to provide type-information for external non-Typescript libraries not written by you.

Comment: In classical inheritance as I know it (C#),  a base class member either 1) mandatorily requires an implementation (inherit from abstract class) or  2) providing an implementation is optional (inherit from virtual class) and it will use the base implementation if you don't provide one . However, a class will never "pretend" to have implementations only to crash at run-time. I understand the need to "pretend" for external libraries, but not in code you are writing yourself. What am I missing?

Comment: Just because you don't have an implementation for a `declare class` *in this compilation* doesn't mean that the compiled file isn't going to run in a context where the class *is* present. This is exactly analogous to .h and .c files in C/C++ - you can include a .h file for definition's sake even if the corresponding .c file isn't part of your compilation, but you need to make sure later at the linker step that all the symbols you do use get resolved to something from a different compilation.

Comment: Separate compilation for large projects is a good example of this, and it's why the compiler has the `--declaration` flag for emitting .d.ts files from existing .ts files. The C# equivalent of not having `declare class` would be if you couldn't reference an external assembly, but instead had to recompile all your dependent base classes into your assembly -- obviously not the right solution!

Comment: I'm afraid that answers it (; Thank you.

Comment: Plus one'd for most brief explanation and example code I've seen so far.

Answer (score 3):

If the file has a `.d.ts` extension, all of the classes are treated as if they were preceded by a `declare` keyword. Declarations don't need an implementation, they just supply type information.

Comment: How is this construct different from an interface besides the need to use 'extends' instead of 'implements' when implementing it? To me it seems similar to a virtual class since it the compiler does not complain when no implementation is provided when extending this class. I'm assuming then that the only difference is base.initialize() cannot be called. Is this correct?