# Return type of a function that returns a chained promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, strong-typing

I have a class that returns a chained promise, first promise's type is `angular.IPromise<Foo>`, the second promise resolves with type `angular.IPromise<Bar>`.

Why is it the return type of `doSomething` `angular.IPromise<Bar>`?

I would have thought that the return type would be `angular.IPromise<Foo>` since that's the first thing that is returned by the function. I am aware that `then()` returns a promise and will wrap what is returned by it into the response of that, but this is still confusing me.

```
import { Something } from '../somewhere';
import { Bar } from '../somewhereelse';

class Test {
    doSomething(): angular.IPromise<Bar> {
        return Something.getFoo() // getFoo() return type angular.IPromise<Foo>
            .then(() => {
                let x: Bar = {};        
                return x; 
            });
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am more than happy to give any more code if required.

Comment: how do you figure that the return type would be `angular.IPromise<Foo>` if you're declaring `Bar` as the type of the return value? typescript does not know about the *runtime* return value, it analyses the code *statically*.

Comment: The return type is angular.IPromise<Bar> - I can easily test that. I was expecting the return type to be angular.IPromise<Foo> since that's the first thing returned by the doSomething() function.

Comment: `.then` is to `Promise` as `.map` is to `Array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing is : you don't return `Something.getFoo()`.
You return `Something.getFoo().then(...)`. Even if promises are used to execute asynchronous tasks, they are returned immediately.

`then()` returning a `angular.IPromise` the returned promise is not the one from `Something.getFoo()` but the one returned by `Something.getFoo().then(...)`

and as the callback provided to `then()` is returning a `Bar` object: `promise.ten(foo=>return new Bar())` your statement actually returns a `Promise<Bar>` object.

as @TsatsuyukiIshi stated, this is the type definition of `angular.IPromise.then` :

```
then<X>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IPromise<X>|X, ...): IPromise<X>
```

this method is generic, and its return type (`X`) depends on the type that is provided as parameter (`(promiseValue: T) => IPromise<X>|X`).

If you replace `X` by `Bar` this is obvious:

```
then(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IPromise<Bar>|Bar, ...): IPromise<Bar>
```

Answer (score 2):

This returns `angular.IPromise<Bar>`, provided the code compiles.

Interfaces can map to any amount of classes, and they can be easily identified with the name prefixed with `I`.

The concrete type would be a detail of Promise implementation, however it satisfies `IPromise<Bar>` as long as it returns a `Bar` on resolve.

EDIT: TypeScript determines it via the template parameter in `then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IPromise<TResult>|TResult, ...): IPromise<TResult>`. This determines the return type of the callback statically. [source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts#L1097)

Also see: [Whats the difference between "declare class" and "interface" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345485/whats-the-difference-between-declare-class-and-interface-in-typescript/14348084#14348084)

Comment: I'm not sure that answers my question completely. I guess I'm asking "why is the return type angular.IPromise<Bar> and not angular.IPromise<Foo>". The call to getFoo() returns angular.IPromise<Foo> and that is the first thing that is returned by doSomething(), so why isn't that the return type of the function?

Comment: @DaveCooper I have added the explanation at your request. I would appreciate you accepting the answer if this satisfies your need.