# Storing multiple objects from observable into a class in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having a bit of a trouble right now in my Angular2 app. I've retrieved multiple objects from my service, thus i want to store each of them to their own class.

I know how to put an object to a class, however how to work it out if there are multiple objects?

**My object**

```
[
  {
    "_key": "2343200",
    "_id": "test/2343200",
    "_rev": "_U9JHQXa---",
    "age": 10,
    "name": "Soy"
  },
  {
    "_key": "2342008",
    "_id": "test/2342008",
    "_rev": "_U9JGn0----",
    "age": 20,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "_key": "2342955",
    "_id": "test/2342955",
    "_rev": "_U9JG46u---",
    "age": 32,
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]
```

Below is my class.

**UserDetails.ts**

```
export class UserDetails {
    key: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Using `foreach()` could be the solution, but how to access each data if i want to manipulate them?

For example, i want to access the class of the second data.

Any kind of help is appreciated! I thank you in advance.

**Edited:** im using my apiservice to retrieve my datas.

```
data: any;

this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe(users=> {
            this.data = users;
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use interfaces instead, I see no need for class here :) [Whats the difference between "declare class" and "interface" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345485/whats-the-difference-between-declare-class-and-interface-in-typescript)

```
export interface UserDetails {
    key: string;
    id: string;
    age: number;
    name: string;
}
```

And when you receive your data, just type it to your interface, in your service you could return an Observable of `UserDetails` array, and in your component you can have the array of type `UserDetails`:

```
data: UserDetails[];

this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe(users=> {
    this.data = users;
})
```

> For example, i want to access the class of the second data. Using `foreach()` could be the solution, but how to access each data if i want to manipulate them?

Yes you can use `forEach` if you need to manipulate your data somehow. Do that inside the callback (subscribe), why you need to do that, is because this is asynchronous. More explanation here: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

```
this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe(users=> {
    this.data = users;
    this.data.forEach(user => {
       console.log(user) 
       // do something!
    })
})
```

---

### Edit:

We got some more information and you need a boolean value to your `UserDetails` to toggle the status of the user, and you want to send the id and status to the backend when this happens.

So first off, add a boolean to your interface, let's call it "status". So add the following property to `status: boolean` to your interface. Since you api don't seem to give a status value, let's iterate each item and add that property in the callback:

```
.subscribe(data => {
  this.data = data;
  this.data.forEach(x => {
    // set initial value to true or false, depending what you want
    x.status = true; 
  });
})
```

Then iterate the users in your template, here I have done it like the following (shortened code). You need to adjust your code accordingly, I see from picture you're using (or want to use) on/off slider :)

```html
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of data">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.status}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="toggleStatus(user)">Toggle Status</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And then your `toggleStatus`:

```ts
toggleStatus(user: UserDetails) {
  user.status = !user.status

  // modify to your actual code
  this.service.sendUser(user.id, user.status)
    .subscribe(....)   
}
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4AdL7QXCRmpMg7O3htuv?p=preview)

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for the late reply, i'll try to solve this matter.

Comment: What i like to achieve is that i am able to turn off and on the status of the people. You can take a look here [link](http://imgur.com/a/x0q2d) @AJT_82

Comment: Well what does this *on/off* mean programatically? Meaning what are turning on and off?

Comment: Oh, and I just realice that you are having two `name` properties in your class/interface, probably a typo?

Comment: Ohh its just a typo. Sorry bout the confusion. Its like turning offline and online kinda thing

Comment: Well, I still don't understand, what should happen in code when you turn online/offline?

Comment: Hmm, i want to get the id of the person and the boolean behind the off and on, then send it to the database.

Comment: As a sidenote, the edit I made to my answer... nowhere in your question did you mention about this status on/off thing, so your question was actually answered already before this edit! Please in future mark what you want *in question* or ask separate questions (so that question does not get too broad). So in theory I wouldn't have needed to provide this edit, but I did anyways cuz I'm bored :D :D So please remember this in the future questions! ;)

Comment: Yes i understand, thank you very much! Indeed it is my intention but, i want to try to solve it by myself. However before reaching to that point i was confused about the implementation of how could i achieve that, thats why i asked this question. But thank you for your time on solving my issue! :D i'll see your demo

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
let jsonArray: IUserDetails[] = [
    ....
];

interface IUserDetails {
    _key: string;
    _id: string;
    _rev: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

class UserDetails {
    key: string;
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;

    constructor(data: IUserDetails) {
        this.key = data._key;
        this.id = data._id;
        this.name = data.name;
        this.age = data.age;
    }
}

const instances: UserDetails[] = jsonArray.map(obj => new UserDetails(obj));
console.log(instances[1]); // UserDetails {key: "2342008", id: "test/2342008", name: "John", age: 20}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20jsonArray%3A%20IUserDetails%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_key%22%3A%20%222343200%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%22test%2F2343200%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_rev%22%3A%20%22_U9JHQXa---%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Soy%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_key%22%3A%20%222342008%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%22test%2F2342008%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_rev%22%3A%20%22_U9JGn0----%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2020%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22John%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_key%22%3A%20%222342955%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%22test%2F2342955%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22_rev%22%3A%20%22_U9JG46u---%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2032%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Jane%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IUserDetails%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_key%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20_rev%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20UserDetails%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20key%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20IUserDetails)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.key%20%3D%20data._key%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.id%20%3D%20data._id%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20data.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.age%20%3D%20data.age%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20instances%3A%20UserDetails%5B%5D%20%3D%20jsonArray.map(obj%20%3D%3E%20new%20UserDetails(obj))%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(instances%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20UserDetails%20%7Bkey%3A%20%222342008%22%2C%20id%3A%20%22test%2F2342008%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22John%22%2C%20age%3A%2020%7D))

---

#### Edit

Based on your comment and the edit you made to your question, you need to do the same inside the `subscribe` handler:

```
data: UserDetails[];

this.apiService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
    this.data = users.map(obj => new UserDetails(obj));
})
```

Comment: It would be that if i use `.map` or `.subscribe` it gives errors which said **Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'UserDetails[]'.** thus another one is that **Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<void>'.** @NitzanTomer

Comment: So you don't have an array of objects, you have an observable. Your question is misleading. Change your question to reflect your real code

Comment: ah yes my bad, im sorry i have caused you trouble. Indeed im using an api service to store these data.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: It gives me `undefined` when i used `console.log(this.instances[0])`. I'll try to solve this problem

Comment: At what point are you trying this? You can do that **only** after the subscriber handler has been invoked. Have you placed that `console.log` inside the handler?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Yes i was wrong on the `console.log()` one. My bad. Yes i am aware of that now. Thank you!