# typescript models from classes, why?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to typescript, I'm using it to build angular apps. 
sometimes I see models like this

```
export interface Item {
    name: string
}
```

and sometimes I see this

```
export class Lesson {

constructor(
    public $key:string)
}
```

with static methods like

```
static fromJson({$key}) {}
```

whats the benefit?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345485/whats-the-difference-between-declare-class-and-interface-in-typescript

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between "declare class" and "interface" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345485/whats-the-difference-between-declare-class-and-interface-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3):

`interface` allows you to create a model with properties only.

However, `class` gives you the advantage to define and use functions.

E.g. if you want to initialize an object, with an interface you have to initialize all the properties, whereas with a class you can do the same with the class `constructor`.

Its really up to the user what they want to use. In my opinion, a model using class gives more flexibility as compared to the interface.