# Typescript declarations for javascript file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using a project mixed with both javascript and typescript.
Declaration files for modules can be easily created using - declare module. But how do I create a declaration for a javascript file in my current folder?

For ex -

```
player.js -
var Player = function() {};
Player.prototype.validate = function() {};
```

How do I create declaration so that I can extend it in typescript. I want to do something like this -

```
player.ts -
let Player = require('./player');
Player.prototype.login = function() {
    this.validate();
}
```

I know the above code will work by setting Player type as any but I won't be able to type check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript does not understand the prototypal syntax / constructor functions: there will be no intellisense. It prefers ES6 classes.

The JavaScript `Player` constructor function is equivalent to this TypeScript class definition:

```js
// -- player.d.ts --
declare class Player {
  validate(): void;
}
```

Then, to add a method to the `Player` class, there's a couple of options:

1. The more TypeScript idiomatic ways: class inheritance or class composition
2. A compromise to keep using the prototypal syntax in TypeScript and still get the intellisense: facade interface

Code examples:

```js
// -- authenticated-player.ts --
import { Player } from './player'; 

// Option #1a: class inheritance
class AuthenticablePlayer extends Player {
  login() {
    this.validate();
  }
}

const p1a = new AuthenticablePlayer();
p1a.login();

// Option #1b: class composition + delegation
class AuthenticablePlayerB {
  private player = new Player(); 

  login() {
    this.validate();
  }

  validate() {
    this.player.validate();
  }
}

const p1b = new AuthenticablePlayerB();
p1b.login();
```

--

```js
// Option #2: prototype extension + facade interface + type assertion
const Player: any = require('./player');

Player.prototype.login = function() {
  this.validate();
}

interface IPlayer {
  login(): void;
  validate(): void;
}

function createPlayer(): IPlayer {
  return new Player();
}

const p2 = createPlayer();
p2.login();
```

Comment: For more details on the difference between `declare class` and `interface`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14348084/1704166

Comment: was hoping there was a way to add to current class without extending it. But I guess I'll have to extend.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interface in your TypeScript file and set that as the type for Player.

```js
interface IPlayer {
  validate();
}

let Player: IPlayer = require('./player');

Player.prototype.login = function() {
    this.validate();
}
```

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'IUser'.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Sabbir's answer here (not enough room in comments)

```
interface IPlayer { 
  validate(): void
  login():void
}
```

old js code

```
var Player = function () { }
Player.prototype.validate = function() {}
```

using in ts project

```
// import / require here, left out for brevity
Player.prototype.login = function() {
    this.validate()
}
```

create a player - login and validate now have auto completion

```
let p: IPlayer = new Player()
p.login()
p.validate()
```

Comment: but auto completion won't work inside the player function

Comment: I don't know your exact project use case but personally I would prefer to create a Typescript Class and copy the JS methods over. Then you will get full code completion. Check the edit

Comment: It's a really big class and I don't want to mix javascript and typescript code.