# Export declare class Incompatible override for member error Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

So I have this class:

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export declare class CommonHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor();
  intercept(request: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler):
    Observable < HttpEvent < any >> ;
  protected _handleError(request: HttpRequest < any > ): (err: any) => void;
  protected _handleUnknownResponse(err: HttpErrorResponse, request: HttpRequest < any > ): void;
  protected _handleDefaultException(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse): void;
  protected _handleInvalidResponse(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse): void;
  protected _publishException(message: string, title ? : string): void;
}
```

And when I try to use it on another class I get a build error & 
WebStorm complains saying:

> Incompatible override for member

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonHttpInterceptor} from 'that class above';
import {HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class positionDataHttpInterceptor extends CommonHttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  protected _handleDefaultException(errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse): void {
    //some code
  }
}
```

- they are both the same version of Angular.

Comment: Why `declare` in `export declare class CommonHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {` ?

Comment: so take declare  out?

Comment: Yeah I mean I'm not sure what it's doing there in the first place?

Comment: That can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348084/9907293 for what ``declare class`` is.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with Visual Studio Code.  It may be WebStorm-specific.  I added the WebStorm tag.

Comment: what errors can you see namely? Please attach screenshots. Note that build errors can't be related to IDE being used