# what is the declare key before function definition in typescript?

Tags: typescript, function, declare

What is the difference between these snippets and what is the usage of declare?

> 1)

```
declare function test();
```

> 2)

```
test(){
}
```

Comment: Or perhaps also [When do you use declare in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352742/when-do-you-use-declare-in-typescript)