# Type declaration of a generic `map` function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, functional-programming, closures, typing

In [exercise #14 of typescript-exercises](https://typescript-exercises.github.io/#exercise=14) you get to annotate the following function:

```ts
export function map(mapper, input) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return map;
    }
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        return function subFunction(subInput) {
            if (arguments.length === 0) {
                return subFunction;
            }
            return subInput.map(mapper);
        };
    }
    return input.map(mapper);
}
```

I've tried to tightly type it using generics but failed:

```ts
type Apply<In, Out> = (element: In) => Out;

declare function subFunction<In2, Out2>(subInput: In2[]): Out2[];
declare function subFunction(): typeof subFunction;

export function map<In, Out>(): typeof map;
export function map<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>): typeof subFunction;
export function map<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>, input: In[]): Out[];

export function map<In, Out>(mapper?: Apply<In, Out>, input?: In[]): ((typeof map) | (typeof subFunction) | Out[]) {
    if (mapper === undefined) {
        return map;
    }
    if (input === undefined) {
        // Line 61 (the error) ahead
        return function subFunction(subInput?: In[]): ((typeof subFunction) | Out[]) {
            if (subInput === undefined) {
                return subFunction;
            }
            return subInput.map(mapper);
        };
    }
    return input.map(mapper);
}
```

The error is:

```
index.ts(61,9): error TS2322: Type '(subInput?: In[] | undefined) => Out[] | ...' is not assignable to type '{ <In2, Out2>(subInput: In2[]): Out2[]; (): typeof subFunction; } | { <In, Out>(): typeof map; <In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>): { <In2, Out2>(subInput: In2[]): Out2[]; (): typeof subFunction; }; <In, Out>(mapper: Apply<...>, input: In[]): Out[]; } | Out[]'.
  Type '(subInput?: In[] | undefined) => Out[] | ...' is not assignable to type '{ <In2, Out2>(subInput: In2[]): Out2[]; (): typeof subFunction; }'.
    Type 'Out[] | ((subInput?: In[] | undefined) => Out[] | ...)' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
      Type '(subInput?: In[] | undefined) => Out[] | ...' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.
```

When I change the return type of `subFunction` @ line 61 to `any`, the error disappears.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the use of the `declare` keyword. I'm not sure exactly where the problem comes in, but the keyword isn't being used correctly here. It should be used to [inform the compiler that a function named `subFunction` exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57352788/8271628), but that isn't the case since `subFunction` is actually declared within `map`.

You can fix this by replacing the declarations with another `type` which I've called `SubMap<In, Out>` here.

```
type Apply<In, Out> = (element: In) => Out;
type SubMap<In, Out> = (subInput?: In[]) => SubMap<In, Out> | Out[];

export function map<In, Out>(): SubMap<In, Out>;
export function map<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>): SubMap<In, Out>;
export function map<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>, input: In[]): Out[];

export function map<In, Out>(mapper?: Apply<In, Out>, input?: In[]): typeof map | SubMap<In, Out> | Out[]
{
    if (mapper === undefined)
    {
        return map;
    }
    if (input === undefined)
    {
        return function subFunction(subInput?: In[]): SubMap<In, Out> | Out[]
        {
            if (subInput === undefined)
            {
                return subFunction;
            }
            return subInput.map(mapper);
        };
    }
    return input.map(mapper);
}
```

Another option is to actually create `subFunction` outside of `map`, although this requires some refactoring.

```
type Apply<In, Out> = (element: In) => Out;

function subFunction<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>): typeof subFunction;
function subFunction<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>, subInput: In[]): typeof subFunction | Out[];

function subFunction<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>, subInput?: In[]): typeof subFunction | Out[]
{
    if (subInput === undefined)
    {
        return subFunction;
    }
    return subInput.map(mapper);
}

export function map<In, Out>(): typeof map;
export function map<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>): typeof subFunction;
export function map<In, Out>(mapper: Apply<In, Out>, input: In[]): Out[];

export function map<In, Out>(mapper?: Apply<In, Out>, input?: In[]): typeof map | typeof subFunction | Out[]
{
    if (mapper === undefined)
    {
        return map;
    }
    if (input === undefined)
    {
        return subFunction(mapper);
    }
    return input.map(mapper);
}
```