# Create a TS function that takes a list of inputFields and FormData and return type safe object with name and value

Tags: typescript

I need to ceate a typescript function that takes 2 params,

1. a list of fields that has a `name` and optional `type`
2. FormData
   Then return a typesafe object with the fieldName as key and fieldValue as value

How it should work

```ts
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', 'John Doe');
formData.append('age', '25');

const fields = [{ name: 'name' }, { name: 'age', type: 'number' }];
const data = extractFormValues(fields, formData);
// {age: 25, name: "John Doe"}
// type being {age: number, name: string}
```

I somehow got it to work in using a object instead of an array

```ts
// const fields = [{ name: 'name' }, { name: 'age', type: 'number' }];
const fields = { name: {}, age: { type: 'number' } };
```

Here's the current solution using object instead of an array

```ts
type IField = {
    name: string;
    type?: string;
};

type IFields = Record<string, IField>;

const extractFormValues = <TFields extends IFields>(fields: TFields, formData: FormData) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(fields);
    const data = {} as {
        [Key in keyof TFields]: TFields[Key]['type'] extends 'number' ? number : string;
    };
    for (const key of keys) {
        const value = formData.get(key) as string;
        if (fields[key]?.type === 'number') data[key] = Number(value);
        else data[key] = value;
    }
    return data;
};

const fields = { name: { name: 'name' }, age: { name: 'age', type: 'number' } };

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', 'JohnDoe');
formData.append('age', '25');

const data = extractFormValues(fields, formData);
```

But I want it to work when I pass a array like this.

```ts
const fields = [{ name: 'name' }, { name: 'age', type: 'number' }]
```

This is how I want it to be, but I want the type safety

```ts
type IField = {
   name: string;
   type?: string;
};

type IFields = IField[];

const extractFormValues = (fields, formData: FormData) => {
   const data = {};
   for (const field of fields) {
      const value = formData.get(field.name) as string;
      if (field.type === 'number') data[field.name] = Number(value);
      else data[field.name] = value;
   }
   return data;
};
```

then run it like this

```ts
const fields = [{ name: 'name' }, { name: 'age', type: 'number' }];

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', 'John Doe');
formData.append('age', '25');
const data = extractFormValues(fields, formData); // {name:'John Doe',age:25}
//    ^? needs to be {name:string,age:number}
```

Comment: ① Please [edit] to reduce this code to be a [mre] without things you're not asking about (e.g., most of `IField`'s properties). I presume you're asking about the call signature typings and not the implementation. If so you might want to reduce further and just ask for the call signature and completely remove the implementation. The minimal code is probably [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/wjo0lN). ② Once you do that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wedzdW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I reduced the extra baggage of the question. Your code provides the correct types, but I don't know how to get an output when using `declare`. 
Thank you for your time btw.

Comment: You don't get output with `declare`. I assumed you could handle the implementation and you were just looking for what type to `return` in your function.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na5v9N) or any number of things to get that type hooked up to an output. Does that fully address the question now, or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz tysm, that addresses the question. Sorry, I didn't realize I could put it in myself.

Comment: @jcalz could you please explain why I need to add `as const` to the array that's passed and make the `IFields` types readonly in the final answer. You can just point me to a link to read if it's too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order for this to possibly work, you need to do something different when you declare `fields`.  The version in your code has the following type:

```
const fields = [{ name: 'name' }, { name: 'age', type: 'number' }]
//    ^? const fields: ({name: string; type?: undefined}|{name: string; type: string})[]
```

Note that the `name` property is `string` in those elements, and `type` is either `string` or `undefined`.  That is a reasonable type for the compiler to infer, because it has no idea what you're going to *do* with `fields` later, and often people change string-valued properties.  But this doesn't work for your use case; you need [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"name"` and `"age"` for the `name` property and like `"number"` for the `type` property.

The easiest way to get that to happen is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). This tells the compiler that you're not going to change anything, and it should therefore try to infer the most precise and specific type possible:

```
const fields = [{ name: 'name' }, { name: 'age', type: 'number' }] as const;
/* const fields: readonly [{
    readonly name: "name";
}, {
    readonly name: "age";
    readonly type: "number";
}] */
```

That has all the information you care about.  It also infers that `fields` is a [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types).  Since `readonly` arrays are *wider* than regular arrays, then if you make your input accept `readonly` arrays it will also accept regular arrays, but not vice versa. So to avoid any issues we can also widen make `IFields` to accept it:

```
type IFields = readonly IField[];
```

And *now* we can give `extractFormValues()` a strong call signature.

---

Here's one way to do it:

```
declare const extractFormValues: <const TFields extends IFields>(
   fields: TFields, formData: FormData
) => { [Key in TFields[number]["name"]]:
      Extract<TFields[number], { name: Key; }>["type"] extends "number" ? number : string;
   }
```

Note that I've used `declare` to just tell TypeScript that this function exists and is of the right type (see [When do you use declare in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57352742/2887218)). In your actual code you would just implement it and then use whatever means necessary to give it that call signature.

The way it works is to iterate over the `name` properties of the array elements (the nested [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `TFields[number]["name"]` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the keys you care about), and then for each one it finds the associated `type` property (by [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)ing the element with a matching `name` from the union of element types, and then indexing into it to get the `type`).  After this it's very similar to your other version, checking against `"number"`.

---

Let's try it out:

```
const formData = new FormData();
const data = extractFormValues(fields, formData);
//    ^? const data: { name: string; age: number; }
```

Looks good.  The type of `data` is `{name: string, age: number}`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#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)